# How to import .ts file inside the .js file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am developing VS code extension. For that I need to know how to import .ts file inside the .js file. I tried deafferent ways to import but it doesn't work for me. So I simply imported axios to check whether "require()" function is working or not. But same error occurred! Can someone help me?

Here's the JS file code and Error says "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

```
(function () {

const axios = require('axios'); // Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();

console.log("hello there from javascript");

document.getElementById("circlein").onclick = function(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("outline")[0];
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } 
    setTimeout(()=>{
      x.style.display = "none"
    },4000);
}

})();
```

Can someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default `require()` is not a valid function in client-side javascript. take a look at [require.js](https://requirejs.org/) as this does extend the client-side, so you use require function.